# Is it true that if one stood on Westminster Bridge with a radio, one would hear the chimes of Big Ben via the radio sooner than in the real world?

Tags: acoustics, speed, radio

I was reading this [review of Damon Krukowski’s *Ways of Hearing* in *The Spectator*](https://www.spectator.co.uk/2019/07/the-bias-against-digital-music-is-more-emotional-than-scientific/) when I stumbled across this claim:

> “And before the renovation of Big Ben began, if you stood on Westminster Bridge just before 6 p.m. with an FM radio, you would hear the bongs on the radio before you heard them in real life — because radio is transmitted at the speed of light, while sound ambles along much more slowly.”

Was/is this at all true? I understand sound waves travel slower than light/radio waves but this seems quite “truthy.”

Comment: To improve this question: can you look up the distance between Westminster Bridge and Big Ben? And the path length a signal would need to take between Big Ben, the radio station and the Westminster Bridge? Without those number we can only guess.

Comment: Another factor is possible sound processing delay before broadcasting, so sound can be both slower or faster then the broadcast.

Comment: Say the person is wearing a headphone, one could make a 3d plot of time it takes the sound to reach the mic at various distances, then the time it takes the signal to reach the radio from the transmitter at various distances, with the third axis showing total transit times (taking processing times into account as a constant, x + y + c = z), comparing that to the time it takes the sound from the bell to get to the person's other ear.

Comment: I have seen a similar question in Physics books, involving a family *in Australia* sitting around their radio, listening to the chimes of Big Ben from London. and hearing them before the "man in the street" in London.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics. A better home would be [skeptics.se].

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I moved my question here because [I was told it was more appropriate for this Stack Exchange as seen here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/44323/22266): **“This is basic physics, and not a "notable claim" suitable for Skeptics.”**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Apparently, yes.

The BBC has a microphone right next to the tower, so they get the soundwaves before nearly anyone else on the street.

Westminster bridge is right next to Big Ben, so it would depend on where on the bridge you stood, as the bridge itself is 820 feet. [Google maps puts the bridge and Big Ben at 249 feet away](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Big+Ben,+Westminster,+London+SW1A+0AA,+UK/Westminster+Bridge,+London+SW1A+2JH,+UK/@51.5008461,-0.125489,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x487604c38c8cd1d9:0xb78f2474b9a45aa9!2m2!1d-0.1246254!2d51.5007292!1m5!1m1!1s0x487604c693fca1a1:0xd697942be6dd609e!2m2!1d-0.1219645!2d51.5008638!3e0) but that includes a 90 degree turn and seems to begin at the end of the bridge, closest to Big Ben.

Big Ben is also 315 feet high, though the sound is probably a bit below that and the bridge has some, admittedly quite a bit less, elevation itself.

If we come up with an estimate about 400 feet for the sound to travel to the Big Ben side of the bridge and perhaps 1000 feet on the far side (say 700 for the middle which appears to be the location for the YouTube video). Sound travels at about 1,100 feet per second, that gives you a rough idea how long it takes between when the clock strikes and when you hear it from Westminster bridge.

I'm less well versed on the radio speed. I have done an experiment talking to a friend on the cell phone from 2 feet away and their voice reached me first in person and a split second later by cellphone, but as noted in the comment below, that's not a good comparison.

The microphone gets the sound, converts it to radio waves, mixes it with the radio station modulation, where it's bounced of the radio tower, reaches the radio, where the modulation is stripped and the initial sound is repeated. I can't get a precise timing on that, but it all happens very fast, but just measuring the speed of light doesn't give the entire estimate.

And, I just want to give props to the BBC for putting a microphone near Big Ben and playing it twice a day. There's something very cool about that, and people have verified that it's a live recording, not a pre-recorded sound, because they occasionally hear sirens from police cars in the background.

Long story short, yes, the radio wins the race [indicated by YouTube test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dwUWtyRP4c), though I had to listen twice before I heard the 2 sounds come in at slightly different times. If the person stood with the radio at the edge of the bridge on the Big Ben side, then it might be too close to discern. The person in the video appears to be standing somewhere quite close to the Big Ben side of the bridge, perhaps 400 or so feet from the ringing bell.

Comment: It's wrong to use cellphone as an example of FM radio: there may be substantial delays due to sound processing in the phone, the cell tower etc.. It'd be better to try a walkie-talkie.

Comment: @Ruslan good point.   I didn't know that.  I'll edit.

Comment: @Ruslan if the signal is still quicker even with the "extra" processing then the point is made...